Reasonable doubt of eye witness's need for glasses in 12 Angry Men
In the 1957 movie 12 Angry Men two witnesses give testimony - an old man with a limp  who claimed to see the accused flee the scene 15 seconds after the murder and a woman who claimed to witness the deed while trying to sleep.  The old man's testimony was questioned because doubts were raised that he could've moved as quickly as he had claimed given his disability. One of the reasons that the woman's testimony was questioned is the jurors recalling her marks on her nose, which suggested she used glasses.
Considering these two points abstractly, the old man's mobility seems (to me) a basis for 'reasonable doubt' because it was deemed that his observable mobility was not consistent with his evidence. But for the woman it seems (to me) a reasonable explanation might have been sunglasses or reading glasses - as was noted by one juror. This means they're considering apparent evidence that could point to explanations other than short-sightedness.
Clearly juries operate according to their own internal logic and discussion based on the evidence they've seen. But in a broad and fairly legally abstract sense, is there any legal guidance or writings on jurisprudence about whether evidence of a potential reason to question a testimony (though it could also have a different explanation - let's say the likelihood is 50:50) should be considered valid basis for 'reasonable doubt'? Assuming all evidence has been presented and jury must now decide. Any authoritative reading references on this aspect would be appreciated.
For sake of clarity this is an abstract question and I am not currently sitting on a jury.

There may be no question on which there is more legal guidance than the question of what constitutes reasonable doubt.

+1 Hopefully, it is understood that the film in question is not about the legal merits of the case, but how the judgement of the jurors is colored by their private experience, biases, etc. Another interesting film along these lines is Rashomon - several witnesses describe the same events from strikingly different perspectives.

Juries get to decide things however they want, this was a big part of racial justice problems in the US south, where no white man would be convicted of doing anything to a Black man.

canada
Both of the concerns you mention may be taken into account by a juror when assessing whether the prosecution has proved an element of the offence (identity, in this case) beyond a reasonable doubt.
Note that the jury is instructed not to assess each piece of evidence piecemeal. They would not be assessing whether they believe the woman beyond a reasonable doubt, or whether they believe the old man beyond a reasonable doubt. They would be assessing whether the prosecution has proved beyond a reasonable doubt that the accused was the person involved in the incident.
Here are some sample jury instructions from the National Judicial Institute:

Now what does the expression “beyond a reasonable doubt” mean? A reasonable doubt is not an imaginary or frivolous doubt. It is not based on sympathy for or prejudice against anyone involved in the proceedings. Rather, it is based on reason and common sense. It is a doubt that arises logically from the evidence or from an absence of evidence.
...
I will explain to you the essential elements that the Crown must prove beyond a reasonable doubt to establish [the accused's] guilt. For the moment, the important point for you to understand is that the requirement of proof beyond a reasonable doubt applies to each of those essential elements. It does not apply to individual items of evidence. You must decide, looking at the evidence as a whole, whether the Crown has proved [the accused's] guilt beyond a reasonable doubt.

That model instruction is informed by guidance from the Supreme Court of Canada in R. v. Lifchus, [1997] 3 S.C.R. 320:


the standard of proof beyond a reasonable doubt is inextricably intertwined with that principle fundamental to all criminal trials, the presumption of innocence;

the burden of proof rests on the prosecution throughout the trial and never shifts to the accused;

a reasonable doubt is not a doubt based upon sympathy or prejudice;

rather, it is based upon reason and common sense;

it is logically connected to the evidence or absence of evidence;

it does not involve proof to an absolute certainty; it is not proof beyond any doubt nor is it an imaginary or frivolous doubt; and

more is required than proof that the accused is probably guilty ‑‑ a jury which concludes only that the accused is probably guilty must acquit.



See also R. v. Ménard, [1998] 2 S.C.R. 109:

the standard of proof beyond a reasonable doubt applies only to the jury’s final evaluation of guilt or innocence and is not to be applied piecemeal to individual items or categories of evidence


Thanks @Jen v helpful. I do appreciate RD applies to the whole case. Yet where everything hangs on a single testimony that id's the accused, it's hard to escape the logic that the RD is bound to the particular doubt about this testimony. So while the term may not legally apply to that doubt, in practice can it amount to the same thing?
So I still wonder how the emergence of a potential reason to doubt evidence should stand against this benchmark? But this is just my musing and I don't expect a concrete answer. But I'll leave the Q open for day or two for others to comment. Thanks again :)

@geotheory Usually the case doesn't hinge on just one piece of evidence or testimony, as the prosecution would not bring such a flimsy case to court. If you have a number of pieces of evidence, where each one might be doubted, but they're all consistent with each other, the chance that they're all wrong is unlikely. That's the "common sense" reasoning mentioned in the answer.

united-states

Is there any legal guidance or writings on jurisprudence about whether
evidence of a potential reason to question a testimony (though it
could also have a different explanation - let's say the likelihood is
50:50) should be considered valid basis for 'reasonable doubt'?

Not much.
If a jury finds that reasonable doubt is present and enters a not guilty verdict, this ruling cannot be appealed.
But evidence of a merely potential reason to question testimony isn't enough to overturn a jury verdict of guilty. Credibility determinations are completely the province of the jury and generally will not be reviewed at all on appeal.
A decision regarding whether to believe that the testimony of a witness is true is called a credibility determination. A finding that the witness important to proving a case is not credible is one legitimate basis to conclude that reasonable doubt exists as to whether a criminal defendant is guilty of a particular charge.
But, as one judge in the U.S. District Court for the District of Colorado summed up the situation (at this link which has currently gone bad):

There is no law on judging credibility.

One model jury instruction for federal judges in the 9th Circuit states:

1.7 CREDIBILITY OF WITNESSES
In deciding the facts in this case, you may have to decide which
testimony to believe and which testimony not to believe. You may
believe everything a witness says, or part of it, or none of it.
In considering the testimony of any witness, you may take into
account:
(1) the witness’s opportunity and ability to see or hear or know the
things testified to;
(2) the witness’s memory;
(3) the witness’s manner while testifying;
(4) the witness’s interest in the outcome of the case, if any;
(5) the witness’s bias or prejudice, if any;
(6) whether other evidence contradicted the witness’s testimony;
(7) the reasonableness of the witness’s testimony in light of all the
evidence; and
(8) any other factors that bear on believability.
You must avoid bias[, conscious or unconscious,] based on a witness’s
race, color, religious beliefs, national ancestry, sexual orientation,
gender identity, gender, or economic circumstances in your
determination of credibility.
The weight of the evidence as to a fact does not necessarily depend on
the number of witnesses who testify about it. What is important is how
believable the witnesses are, and how much weight you think their
testimony deserves.
Comment
The Committee recommends that the jurors be given some guidelines for
determining credibility at the beginning of the trial so that they
will know what to look for when witnesses are testifying.
See also Instruction 3.9 (Credibility of Witnesses) for the
corresponding instruction to be given at the end of the case.


Is it credibility of the female witness exampled in the question that is in doubt? I doubt that the suspicion is that she is intentionally lying. Rather, she may just truly believe that she saw what she says she did.

@Greendrake: That is still credibility. There was a case awhile back where they got multiple witnesses to testify the moon was up when the almanac said it was not. The jury finding all of the witnesses were not credible in any part for that colossal testimony is a perfectly reasonable result, no matter what they think they saw.

@Greendrake Joshua is right. Anything that cases the correctness of the testimony of a witness is credibility. This is true even if it is sincerely believed by the witness to be true. Indeed, judges in bench trials heavily prefer to resolve credibility disputes on any possible ground other than a finding that someone is outright lying.

@Joshua thanks for the interesting moon example - though digging suggests this may not be "awhile back". It was apparently Abraham Lincoln! https://www.jstor.org/stable/40186950?seq=1

@ohwilleke "Credibility determinations ... generally will not be reviewed at all on appeal." Does this mean that one could introduce a not-credible witness but on appeal their testimony would suddenly become believed as fact?

@StephanSamuel: No. It would only be believed as fact if it were at the trial court.

Other than in cases of jury tampering or violating the requirements of not  seeking/using unsubmitted evidence, a NOT guilty verdict means that the prosecution failed to convince the jury to vote guilty.
Why doesn’t really matter, and any attempt to make it matter, eliminates the  political purpose behind a jury. You can’t both say that they are free to make a judgment and then reject that judgement because you don’t agree with it.
It is up to the jurors to decide, for themselves, not for other jurors, whether they were convinced enough to convict.
